# Android How to convert .raw data to .mp3 file?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, converters, audio-recording

I am new in android I want to convert .raw file to .mp3 please help me to convert it. 
my code is.

```
private void initRecorder() {
    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    mBuffer = new short[bufferSize];
    toTransform = new double[bufferSize];
    mRecorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
}

 if (!mIsRecording) {
                        Log.e("bbkk", "KKBB");
                        mIsRecording = true;
                        mRecorder.startRecording();
                        mRecording = getFile("raw");
                        startBufferedWrite(mRecording);
                    }

   private File getFile(final String suffix) {
    Time time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();
    return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), time.format("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S") + "." + suffix);
}
```

Comment: No error but , i need to use .read method but MediaRecorder don't support it. #Vishal Raj

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MediaRecorder` and set you media recorder properly with encoders and output format and that will save you file in mp3 format:

```
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(getFile("mp3"));
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
mRecorder.prepare();
mRecorder.start();
```

If you have to use `AudioRecorder` you should check out [this](https://github.com/yhirano/Mp3VoiceRecorderSampleForAndroid) example of how to convert it to mp3

Comment: Hi,@shem, Thanks for your help but,I am using AudioRecorder, Not mediaRecorder,